# Creating RDF file using csv file contain date wise value as input

Tags: python, rdflib, turtle-rdf

I have a data as shown in the figure and want to convert it into RDF file. I have use following code
[image: My data in CSV]

```
#import libraries 
import pandas as pd #for handling csv and csv contents
from rdflib import Graph, Literal, RDF, URIRef, Namespace #basic RDF handling
from rdflib.namespace import FOAF , XSD #most common namespaces
import urllib.parse #for parsing strings to URI's
#Read file
df=pd.read_csv("filename.csv",sep="\t",quotechar='"')
#creating graph
g = Graph()
continent = Namespace('http://example.org/continent/')
loc= Namespace('http://mylocations.org/addresses/')
schema = Namespace('http://schema.org/')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    g.add((URIRef(continent+row[0]), RDF.type, URIRef(continent+'Iso_code')))
    g.add((URIRef(continent+row[1]), RDF.type, URIRef(continent+'Continent')))
    g.add((URIRef(continent+row[2]), RDF.type, URIRef(continent+'Location')))
    g.add((URIRef(continent+row[2]), URIRef(continent+'is_in'), URIRef(continent+row[1])))
    g.add((URIRef(continent+row[2]), URIRef(continent+'total_cases'), Literal(row[4], datatype=XSD.integer)))
    g.add((URIRef(continent+row[2]), URIRef(continent+'date'), Literal(row[3],datatype=XSD.date)))
# save graph
g.serialize('mycsv2rdf.ttl',format='turtle')
```

Did I create rdf correctly ?
the created file have data like.

```
@prefix ns1: <http://example.org/continent/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
ns1:AFG a ns1:Iso_code .
ns1:Afghanistan a ns1:Location ;
ns1:date "0101-01-01"^^xsd:date,
    "0201-01-01"^^xsd:date,
    "0301-01-01"^^xsd:date,
    "0401-01-01"^^xsd:date,
    "0501-01-01"^^xsd:date,
    "0601-01-01"^^xsd:date,
    "2401-01-01"^^xsd:date,
    "2501-01-01"^^xsd:date,
    "2601-01-01"^^xsd:date,
    "2701-01-01"^^xsd:date,
    "2801-01-01"^^xsd:date,
    "2901-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
ns1:is_in ns1:Asia ;
ns1:total_cases 1,
    2,
    4 .
ns1:Asia a ns1:Continent .
```

Value is not inserted with date wise. help me what i have to do.
how to insert date wise value into graph.

Answer (score 0):

No, your data is not correct, in several ways:

- your dates need to be parsed correctly. Consider using using Python's `datatime.strtotime()` and then supply the date object to RDFlib's `Literal` class
- you have declared a class of `Iso_code` and created instances of it, e.g. `ns1:AFG`, but you've not linked anything to it.

Actually, none of your RDF makes sense: you need to have a subject, probably `ns1:Afghanistan` (but note that your URI for `ns1` contains `/continent/` and yet Afghanistan is not a continent) and then links thigs to it. You've declared a series of un-related subjects, e.g. `ns1:AFG`, `ns1:Afghanistan`, `ns1:date`.

You probably want something like this:

```
@prefix ns1: <http://example.org/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix time: <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#> .

ns1:AFG a ns1:Iso_code .

ns1:Asia a ns1:Continent .

ns1:Afghanistan 
    a ns1:Location ;
    ns1:hasIsoCode ns1:AFG ;
    ns1:hasDatedCases [
       time:hasTime "2020-02-24"^^xsd:date ;
       ns1:totalCases 1 ;
       ns1:newCases 1 ;
    ] ,
    [
       time:hasTime "2020-02-25"^^xsd:date ;
       ns1:totalCases 1 ;
       ns1:newCases 0 ;
    ] ,
    ...
    ns1:is_in ns1:Asia ;
.
```